# angular, get the header in a redirect?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have another address that will be added to mine developed in Angular 9/10.
it will pass some parameters in the header and I want to receive it when I access my '/home' and from there take some action.

flow:
another site (add the header) and redirect> my site ...

ngOnInit () start to check if received any header?

Answer (score 0):

Normally ActivatedRoute can be used to get the header data. If you check the documentation of ActivatedRoute, you can use "data" instead of params and get the values.

For an example here based on documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#description

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
/* . . . */
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
/* . . . */

@Component({
/* . . . */
})
export class ActivatedRouteComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const id: Observable<string> = route.params.pipe(map(p => p.id));
    const url: Observable<string> = route.url.pipe(map(segments => segments.join('')));
    // route.data includes both `data` and `resolve`
    const user = route.data.pipe(map(d => d.user));
  }
}
```

Here if you see the **const user = route.data.pipe(map(d => d.user));**, this is what you may need to do.